# Use an excel cell D5 for path. Open each workbook(both formats xls and xlsx) in that path and save each sheet in those workbooks in PDF format

Tags: excel, vba

The target is to save all the sheets in Output folder. Please tell me where i'm going wrong. When I run the code only the last line i.e., "strfile = Dir" is throwing error

```
Sub converter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim strfolder As String, strfile As String, strdest As String
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

strfolder = Sheet1.Range("D5").Value

'Create a new folder named output
MkDir strfolder & "\" & "Output"
strdest = Dir(strfolder & "\" & "Output" & "\")
strfile = Dir(strfolder & "\")
Do While strfile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strfolder & "\" & strfile)
    For Each Sheet In wb.Sheets
        Sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strdest & Sheet.Name & ".pdf", , , , , , False
    Next Sheet
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    strfile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: someone help please

Comment: Please can you show the code you currently have.

Answer (score -1):

try this code running from any module in vbe. Paste path to folder with excel files (str_FolderPath ) and path to folder where u want to save pdf
(str_DestPath ). if u dont want open pdf file after publish delete true parametr from lane with export.

```
Sub WStoPDF()
Dim str_FolderPath As String, str_MyFile As String, str_DestPath As String
Dim wb_WB As Workbook
Dim ws_WS As Worksheet

'   path to folder
str_FolderPath = "\"
str_DestPath = "\"
str_MyFile = Dir(str_FolderPath)    '   & "\*.xlsx"

Do While str_MyFile <> ""
    Set wb_WB = Workbooks.Open(str_FolderPath & "\" & str_MyFile)
    For Each Sheet In wb_WB.Sheets
        Sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, str_DestPath & Sheet.Name & ".pdf", , , , , , True
    Next Sheet
    wb_WB.Close savechanges:=False
    str_MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub converter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strfolder As String, strfile As String, strdest As String
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
strfolder = Sheet1.Range("D5").Value
strfile = Dir(strfolder & "\")
MkDir strfolder & "\" & "Output"
strdest = Dir(strfolder & "\" & "Output" & "\")
Do While strfile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strfolder & "\" & strfile)
    For Each Sheet In wb.Sheets
        Sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strdest & Sheet.Name & ".pdf", , , , , , False
    Next Sheet
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    strfile = Dir
Loop

End Sub

Comment: Sir, in the code i have commented just now, last step i.e., I'm facing error at strfile = Dir. Could you help me with this

Comment: strdest should be without dir. strdest = strfolder & "\" & "Output" & "\"

Comment: Thank you so much, Tomasz. You have really helped me a lot.

Comment: Sir, all the pdfs are containing these ".xls" & ".xlsx" in the file names. How do I remove them. Thanks in advance

Comment: it shouldnt. if u use upper code u should have file names strdest & Sheet.Name & ".pdf".send final code which you use.

Comment: Left(wb.Name, InStr(wb.Name, ".xls") - 1) + "-" + Sheet.Name... I used this for the PDF file name sir and it is working fine. Thank you so much for all your help.